# Is there a way to properly integrate two (or more) Spring-Boot projects?

Tags: java, spring, maven, gradle, spring-boot

Just to better understand Spring: for instance, I would like to develop a web portal and the data access layer (with JPA/Hibernate/MySQL etc.) as different **Spring-Boot** projects, by using Maven or Gradle in order to integrate the two *pieces*.

Is there a way to do that? There are also other best practices to organize a big project that involves many people?

Can I define a main class for each of them or that may cause issues?

**Note:** in this scenario, the web portal represents the integration point: it imports DAL's jar, not the other way around.

Comment: You don't want the data access layer to be runnable, do you?

Answer (score 2):

What I would do personally in your scenario, is to make the web portal module a Spring Boot project, while the data access layer would not be a Spring Boot project (since it should not be runnable on it's own). 
All the auto configuration would be done by the web portal module (which of course would need to include the data access layer as a dependency).

The unit and integration tests for the data access layer could easily be run with or without a test only Spring Boot configutation on that module

Comment: Mmm... Should I define the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency for the web portal? (I reckon I don't.)

Comment: In order for the data access module to be able to compile on it's own, and for the test to be able to run on there own (not as part of the build of the whole project), the module itself needs to have dependencies to Spring Data JPA. Once you have the proper dependencies in the data access module, you do not need to add `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`, since all that starts does is force the inclusion of the dependencies you will already have.  `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` does not contain any Spring Boot code.

Comment: But that doesn't mean you shouldn't include it. Personally I would: it's a good shortcut to a consistent set of dependencies.

Comment: @DaveSyer Yes of course you could add it to be more consistent :)

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly possible.  Once you've got the hang of it the setup is easy - just a config class in the library and an @Import in the consuming application.

Note: I've only tested this so far with JPA and autowiring, I believe it should work with most common Spring features but can't confirm this yet.

So in your library in the src/main/etc..

```
@Configuration
@EntityScan(basePackages = "uk.co.company.name.models")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "uk.co.company.name" })
@EnableJpaRepositories("uk.co.company.name")
public class LibraryNameConfig {

}
```

Then in src/test

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Import({ LibraryNameConfig.class})
public class FakeTestApp {
    public static void blah() {}
}
```

And test as normal

```
 @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = FakeTestApp.class)
public class TestTestModelWiredUp {

    @Autowired
    TestModelService testModelService;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }
}
```

That should work nicely with a standard gradle/mvn to produce a tested jar.

Then to use it in another Spring Boot application include the jar as a dependency as you would standardly

To make it work in the application you just need to @Import it again as above.  I've set up both my application and libraries in the same way with a Configuration Class that's imported. There appear to be dozens of ways to configure things in Spring Boot with annotations, this setup works for me.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Import({ LibraryNameConfig.class, RealAppConfig.class})
public class SpringBootApp {
    public static void aFunction() {}
}
```

You'll need an application.properties in the Library for testing, but it will use the applications ones when included as a library.